# Saving to elastic search from Google Dataflow streaming job

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, google-cloud-dataflow

I am saving data to BigQuery through a Google Dataflow Streaming job.

I want to insert this data into elastic search for rapid access.

Is it a good practice to call logstach from dataflow through http?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Apache Beam Java SDK has a [connector to read from/write to Elastic search](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.java). This should optimize the IO to be consistent with the Beam model.

Comment: Rescuing @searain's answer: Check also https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/dataflow-elasticsearch-indexer